# how i can make a sort system depend on Character

Tags: php, mysql

i mean i have songs table ok??
i want to make some things like that
a | b | c | d
click on a select from the database the songs that start by a Character
how i can do that by the mysql???

Comment: ooh, just **one** more additional question mark would have gotten me to answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is in Python because I can't be bothered to look up the crappy PHP syntax:

```
qry = "select song_name from songs where left(song_name, 1) = '%s'" % letter
```

This assumes that you haven't foolishly used a case sensitive collation as well.  In case you were being silly and did that well:

```
qry = "select song_name from songs where left(lower(song_name), 1) = '%s'" %
      letter.lower()
```

Comment: Right. Because string assignment in PHP is just **so** insane looking. Uh huh.

Comment: Really? All he even needs is the MySQL query line, I'm sure he can figure out how to use that in PHP.

Comment: Yep as you can see from the OP the bar to entry for PHP is rather low.  And those stupid $ symbols everywhere are irksome.

Comment: Quick suggestion about readability, SQL is less irksome to scan when you capitalize keywords/functions, i.e., `SELECT troll FROM comments WHERE username = 'you'`

Comment: Uppercase is for IBM mainframe programmers. It just looks like the code yelling at you and feels rather unnecessary - especially since there's a nice sql mode in Emacs that color codes your sql instead.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can use a LIKE statement to achieve this.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `title` LIKE 'a%'
```

That will select anything where the title starts with an 'a', the % allows for anything after that. I'm not sure if this is case-sensitive or not (I don't believe it is), can someone confirm either way?

Answer (score 1):

Retrieved from: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/2320.htm

```
select * FROM `table` WHERE LEFT(`value`, 1) NOT BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z'
```